# Function of ellipse in the first quadrant correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, proof-explanation, conic-sections

If $y = \frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ is the top half of the ellipse, shouldn't the function for the ellipse in the first quadrant be half the area of the top half of the ellipse? Why is it $1/4$ of the area if the function given is for the top half of the ellipse?

[image]

Comment: Note they only integrate from $0$ to $a$ so that only counts the right half of the top, not the whole top part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area enclosed by the ellipse consists of four equal parts, one in each quadrant. Therefore the area in the first quadrant is one quarter of the total area.